# How do you access horizon on a web browser?

Tags: horizon

I can't find a tutorial on how to use it, what to download, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to get started is by using the public horizon that is hosted by stellar.org (horizon.stellar.org). Horizon is just an HTTP api that is layered on top of stellar-core (with a few extra bells and whistles) -- so you could make your http requests directly to it like the [Stellar Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/#explorer?network=test) does.

However, you're probably better off using one of the [supported Stellar SDKs](https://www.stellar.org/developers/reference/) -- pick one of them in a language that you're comfortable with.

Start with https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/index.html to get a big picture of how the different pieces fit in, then move to the next step that shows you some actual code samples (https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/get-started/create-account.html).

The [Stellar developers](https://www.stellar.org/developers/) site has a lot of other helpful articles on it. I encourage you to read through it, especially the Guides and Reference & SDKs sections.

Comment: Thank you Paul. You've been a great help. Which language do you think is the easiest and most flexible? Something similar to Apache would be good.

Comment: Here's a list of a few SDKs https://www.stellar.org/developers/reference/

Comment: The advice I give to most people is to use the language you're most comfortable with. Apache is a web server, not a programming language -- so there's not much I can offer in terms of similar choices. That said, if you're a beginner, a lot of people like Python. I personally prefer modern JavaScript, and the Stellar JavaScript SDK is very fleshed out and officially supported -- but a lot of beginners have trouble with JavaScript's warts.